# Adding ram to my hp laptop

Tags: ram, frequency

I want to add 4gb ram to my laptop but confused which one should I buy as I can't figure out my ram type.

`sudo dmidecode --type memory | less` is giving this output

```
Handle 0x0025, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Number Of Devices: 2
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0025
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Kingston
        Serial Number: 43522522
        Asset Tag: 9876543210
        Part Number: HP687515-H66-MCN  
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.35 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

Can I add 4 GB ram? Which one should I buy one with 1.5V or 1.35V? In speed, it is showing 1600 MT/s. Should I go with 800 MHz or 1600 MHz because in some article it is mentioned that 1600 MT/s effective speed is 800 MHz.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, what model of HP laptop do you have.

Comment: And then it depends on how many slots for RAM the LAPTOP have and how many is occupied.

Comment: And its a 1,35 volt RAM type, you can see it if you google on the `Part Number: HP687515-H66-MCN`

Comment: And G = Giga, B = Byte and b = bit!

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I think my laptop has 2 slots(in windows cpuz showed slot 1 and slot 2). I have hp notebook product number: V5D75PA#ACJ. Serial number: CND6055G70

Comment: If it's 1.35 V ram but can I/ should I add 1.5V ram with it? Will it work?

Comment: Please answer all questions and add info to your question as I have requested above!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to me like a request for hardware recommendations. There's an argument to be made that it is: a hardware recommendation (if correct) would answer it. But it isn't asking for specific product suggesions. It's asking how to find out what *kind* of product to buy, based on information *provided by Ubuntu*. Even if this couldn't be found that way (which it can) it could still be answered with an explanation of how the information obtained from within the system is limited. Questions that present information shown *within Ubuntu* and ask how to interpret it are generally on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the spec for your current 4G RAM SODIMM. Get a similar spec for your additional RAM. Always configure memory with matched-pair SODIMMs.

```
HP687515-H66-MCN Kingston 4GB 
PC3-12800 DDR3-1600MHz 
non-ECC Unbuffered 
CL11 204-Pin SoDimm 
1.35V Low Voltage Single Rank Memory Module
```

See https://starmicroinc.net/kingston-4gb-pc3-12800-ddr3-1600mhz-non-ecc-unbuffered-cl11-204-pin-sodimm-1-35v-low-voltage-single-rank-oem-memory-hp687515-h66-mcn/

Comment: Will [this](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00CQ35GYE/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_e0z9EbCTPTMTT) work?

Comment: @YogiKatba Giggle... the price on that is $2500! Google HP687515-H66-MCN, or go to crucial.com, or use the example that I gave in my answer... $19.00.

Comment: It's actually 2500 rupees. It showing wrong info in US. I can't buy the product you linked because I don't live in US. I want to know if my linked product is single rank and sodium or not. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @YogiKatba Oh! rupees! It looks like it should work. The best thing would be to examine your existing SODIMM and make sure the chip count is the same... either 4 or 8 RAM chips, but you have to look at both sides of the SODIMM. Make sure to use proper ESD procedures if you're going to touch your SODIMM or motherboard.